# MySQL (Version : 5.7.21-ndb-7.5.9-cluster) use Full table scan for simple Select Query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Currently, my query takes 8 seconds to complete.

Query is :

```
SELECT CI FROM MyTable WHERE CI = 9787988;
```

and index also available like:

```
CREATE INDEX nidx_MyTable_CI ON MyTable(CI) USING BTREE;
```

NDB MyTable has 6.2 Million records. CI is not a primary key and having null values. MyTable has 12 Columns with `VARCHAR`/`INT`/`DATE` data types. `ANALYZE TABLE` executed without any issues. `FORCE INDEX` also returns full table scan and it took 8 seconds to complete.

[image: Work bench]

How can I optimize the query to execute faster?

Comment: What is the cardinality of the `CI` column?  If the cardinality be very low, then using an index might actually hurt, which would explain your output.

Comment: CI Column has more or less an unique value. so, cardinality equal to no of records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the datatype of `CI` is `VARCHAR`, then quote the `9787988`.  Else, it must convert each string `CI` to a number to do the test, hence a table scan.

(You are likely to get faster answers from us when you provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, you save my time.